# Get list of TopicAssignments for each FeedItem while querying FeedItems?

Tags: soql

I can't figure out how to do this in one query. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Use below SOQL query:

```
SELECT Id, Title, Body, Status, (SELECT Id, TopicId FROM TopicAssignments) from FeedItem
```

### Note

You can get child relationship names from [getChildRelationships()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeSObjectResult_getChildRelationships)

```
for (Schema.ChildRelationship cr: Schema.SObjectType.FeedItem.getChildRelationships()) {
    if (String.isNotBlank(cr.getRelationshipName())) {
        system.debug('Child Object Relationship Name => '+cr.getRelationshipName());
    }
}
```

Child relationships for FeedItem:

[image]